# How to generate a model, whose table in stored in a different database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I work with an app, which uses three different databases. I want to create a model and store its table in one particular database, which is not the default *appname_development* database. How do I tell the rails generator where to create the DB table for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you can't. You can't tell the model generator which database to use to create the table (out of the box).

You'd need to change the generated migration yourself to target the database you want using [establish_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection). Something like:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:"which_db_#{Rails.env}")
conn.create_table :my_table do |t|
```

Instead of the usual call to `create_table` that gets generated for you.

You'll also need to add the `establish_connection` call to any models.

---

However, you could provide your own templates for the the generation of the your migration and model though in order to add those lines for any generated model. There's more details in the [generators guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) but you should be able to provide versions of the files to generate a model and a migration. You'd then have to react to a variable passed in on the `rails generate` to specify which db to use. Might be a bit fiddly but probably worth it if you're going to get generating a lot of models in different places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `establish_connection` method.

```
class SomeClassInDb1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "db_1_#{Rails.env}"
end


class SomeClassInDb2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "db_2_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

and in your config/database.yml

```
development:
  # your normal db settings

db_1_development:
  # config for db 1 in development env

db_2_development:
  # config for db 2 in development env

db_1_test:
  # config for db 1 in test env
db_2_test:
  # config for db 2 in test env

db_1_production:
  # config for db 1 in production env

db_2_production:
  # config for db 2 in production env
```

Comment: might be `establish_connection`  :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it's slightly off the topic. You describe how to connect your models to different databases, but this assumes that the tables already exist in the databases. My question refers to whether it's possible to tell Rails where to create the tables upon model creation. Danke trotzdem :)